# Warping the Android UI for a curved screen

Tags: android, android-layout, opengl-es, android-theme

I'd like to know how I can warp (perform geometric correction) of the entire Android UI for projector display onto a curved screen.

OpenGL is a core library on the Android platform and I know that OpenGL ES allows for mapping of each screen frame as a texture to a user-defined mesh grid.

How can I leverage this to transform the entire UI (across all apps & themes) as seen in the image below?

I've also looked into the wearables APIs but that seems to be limited to individual apps and doesn't do warping.

If I can't warp the entire UI then I'd like to perhaps warp and display each frame from the Android TV HDMI-In. The SDK doesn't seem to leverage Open GL. Can I override it and do the transformation?

[image: Warp screen]

Answer (score 0):

Google Cardboard does something like this to correct for lens distortion.  Google hasn't officially released the source, but they released the binary under a permissive Open Source license, so people have taken the liberty of decompiling it.

The class where most of the magic happens is called [`DistortionRenderer`](https://github.com/raasun/cardboard/blob/master/src/com/google/vrtoolkit/cardboard/DistortionRenderer.java).  Basically, the scene is rendered into a texture buffer, which is then used to texture a `DistortionMesh`.  It sounds like the same technique would work for you, but you'd have to come up with your own way of generating a distortion mesh that corresponds to the projector screen.

Comment: I missed that you wanted to do this for all apps, not just your own.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Kevin. If I can't warp the entire UI then at least the HDMI-passthrough / capture app that came with my Zidoo X9 Media Player. The source code is open and I think it can be done on their [disHDMI() class](https://github.com/zidootech/zidoorecorder/blob/master/src/com/zidoo/recorder/tool/HdmiTool.java#L4).
DistortionRenderer may be inefficient (not sure if it will force me to render for left + right display).

Comment: Your tip led me to find [BitmapMesh[(https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/eclair-sholes-release/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/BitmapMesh.java) which looks like it has the methods to make it work. I'm wondering if I can leverage this on the HDMI In tool.

Hoping I can find an Android developer to work on this project for me. Not finding the right skills on [Freelancer and other forums](https://www.freelancer.com/projects/Software-Architecture/Android-Warping-Custom-Geometric/#/details) 
My day job is Solution Architect.I read/understand but can't code